# A power series problem, find ROC

Tags: real-analysis, power-series

Well, I am always wrong in calculation of Radius of Convergence $R$ of a Power series. Would anyone help me to find this one? $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nx^n$ where $a_0=0$ and $a_n= \sin(n!)/n!$, I guess $R\ge 1$, is it?

Comment: Do you know a good bound for $|\sin n!|$?

Comment: the fastest way to reason here is to compare this with the power series of the exponential function (which is $\infty$)

Comment: gerry,I know $|sinx|\le |x|$, Thomas I did not get your point.

Comment: @Mex There is a much better (constant) bound.

Comment: so here It will be $n!$

Comment: $|\sin x|\leq|x|$ is a good bound when $x$ is small, but for large $x$ one should use $|\sin x|\leq1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wouldn't $\,|\sin n!|\leq 1\,$ be a sharper inequality? With it you can even try absolute convergence for any given $\,x\in\mathbb{R}\,$ and get a pretty big ROC...

Answer (score 1):

The formula for the radius of convergence of a power series is
$$
\frac1R=\limsup_{n\to\infty}a_n^{1/n}\tag{1}
$$
That and [Stirling's Approximation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation) should answer your question.